# Table with intervals in cells

Tags: r, tabular

I'm trying to fit some confidence intervals for a statistic into a table, however the structure is tricky for me. I want it to look like this

| Level | Percentile | Student's |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 95% | [p1, p2] | [t1, t2] |

Where p1, p2 and t1, t2 are numbers calculated, in part, with use of the `quantile` function.
Sample code, where I've just generated some random numbers for use in calculation.

```
    set.seed(42) #Arbitrary random seed
    alk <- rexp(800,rate=1) #some random numbers
    
    N <- 10^4
    #Reserving space
    Tstar <- numeric(N)
    xbarstar <- numeric(N)
    
    xbar <- mean(alk)
    n <- length(alk)
    
    for (i in 1:N)
    {
      bootsamp <- sample(alk,size=n,replace=T)
      Tstar[i] <- (mean(bootsamp) - xbar)/(sd(bootsamp)/sqrt(n)) #for t-confidence
      xbarstar[i] <- mean(bootsamp) #For the bootstrap percentile calc.
    }
    
    alpha<-0.05
    #bootstrap t Confidence interval
    boot.t <-xbar - quantile(Tstar,c(1-alpha/2,alpha/2))*sd(alk)/sqrt(n)
    #bootstrap percentile
    boot.p <- quantile(xbarstar,c(alpha/2,1-alpha/2))
    
    nams<-c("level","percentile","student")
    A <- matrix(data=nams,nrow=1,ncol=3)
    A <- rbind(A,c("95%","[1.004, 1.1536]","[1.00131, 1.148672]"))
    print(A)
```

This is, of course, horrible since I'm manually putting in the interval values, but it's just to give you an idea of what I want - I know using a matrix probably isn't the right way either.
Particularly, I'm stumped by how to get the `[1.004, 1.1536]` into a single cell. I know I can reference the two numbers, individually, by using `boot.t[[1]]` and `boot.t[[2]]`, or alternatively get them both, as a vector, by using `unname(boot.t)` - but that doesn't help me arrange them into a single cell, as written above.
In addition, printing the matrix or doing `as.table(A)` gives these annoying headers of [1], [2], [3] or A, B, C for the columns/rows that I don't want.

P.s. the math here is not really important, I just need help arranging the results in a nice tabular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` with `toString` to format the table.

```
A <- data.frame(level = '95%', 
                Percentile = sprintf('[%s]', toString(round(boot.t, 3))), 
                 Student = sprintf('[%s]', toString(round(boot.p, 3))))
A

#  level     Percentile        Student
#1   95% [1.004, 1.154] [1.001, 1.149]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks for the help. Marked as solved.